# Can I join the dark brotherhood as a werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I completed innocence lost and slept, but haven't been abducted. I'm a werewolf, does this prevent me from being abducted and joining them?

Comment: Well since one of the cures of being a werewolf is to become a vampire, and since you can't become a vampire without starting the quest, I'd say no.

Comment: @Ben is disagree. You do not need to become a vampire in order to cure yourself as a werewolf.

Comment: @JimJones no, you do not *need* to. What I'm saying is that you *can* cure the werewolf curse by becoming a vampire. It's an "exploit" that exists in the game

Comment: okay nevermind.

Comment: Just want to say being a werewolf does not prevent your character from sleeping(a requirement for advancing the quest to join the Brotherhood). What is does do is prevent you from gaining a rested bonus from sleeping.

Answer (score 13):

> I'm a werewolf, does this prevent me from being abducted and joining them?

No, you can join the Dark Brotherhood, even if you're a werewolf.

Since you have completed Innocence Lost, you need to wait for a few days and enter a city (**Example:** Whiterun). A courier will give you a note that says "We Know". And then sleep in a bed and you'll be kidnapped.

if you speak to Arnbjorn, he reveals that he is a werewolf, meaning The Player is not the only werewolf in the DB.

Answer (score 3):

No it shoudldn't
I've done almost the same same, getting in the companions Circle and becoming a werewolf after joining the dark brotherhood.

In fact being a werewolf gives you an aditional speech whith one of the brotherhood which is indeed a werewolf ([Astrid's Husband](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Arnbjorn)).

Quoting the wikia

> > He is an ex-member of the Companions. He was asked to leave because his "unorthodox" methods were offensive to other members. It is
> >     unclear what these methods were or how they were offensive, however,
> >     given his current status, it seems possible he used underhanded,
> >     duplicitous techniques that would have offended the Companions' sense
> >     of honor. He joined The Circle and became a werewolf prior to his
> >     expulsion.
>
> He initially disapproves of the Dragonborn, showing a rude attitude,
>   but after several successful assassinations, he begins to respect and
>   even envy the Dragonborn.
>
> **If the Dragonborn is also a werewolf, however, he will immediately know and react a bit more amiably.** Regardless of whether they are a
>   werewolf or not, Arnbjorn will use little nicknames such as
>   "lambshank," "beef roast," "tidbit," or "hamhock." He says not to take
>   offense from the nicknames.

So, being a werewolf does not prevent you from joining the dark brotherhood.

Finally, coming to your issue, have you tried going to sleep in your house ?

Quoting [Wikia](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Brotherhood_(Skyrim)) again:

> 24 hours after Innocence Lost has been completed, a courier will
>   appear to the Dragonborn in any city, with a note saying, "We know." A
>   black hand-print is above the words. After receiving the note,
>   **sleeping in any bed for any amount of time will begin the next phase**
>   of the quest (the acquisition of this note is optional).

Comment: Its easy to see... Where it says if the dragonborn is ALSO a werewolf... It's implied that it doesnt matter if you are a werewolf ir not, in order yo join

Comment: Better than the first answer since it provides some evidence.

Comment: Mind my first comment. This answer is useful.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can because the one member is in fact a werewolf so if you do the companions quest then go to the dark brotherhood quest they will still accept you,.

Comment: This doesn't really add anything that the other answer hasn't already covered.